# usability of a method added onto Function.prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing an example program that does the same task, both using jQuery, and then in plain JavaScript.  For the jQuery portion I have the code wrapped in $(document).ready(), and for the JavaScript part I have an event listener to call main() when the "DOMContentLoaded" event is fired.

There is a particular function that I would like to make accessible to both programs, and although I would like to know any good patterns for doing this, I had an idea and now am more interested in why my idea is not working!

As it stands, the function I need (called Modulo) is in the jQuery portion.  So I thought of assigning the function to the Function.prototype like so:

```
Function.prototype.Modulo = function(){
    var input = $('#inputBox').val();       
    var output = "";
    ...
    //arbitrary code here
    Output(output);
};
```

After doing this, when I look at Function.prototype.Modulo in the console, it contains the function, and I am also able to console.log-out the value of Function.prototype.Modulo from the JavaScript portion of the program.  My question is, why can't I call this like a regular function?

I am trying to call it on the jQuery side like so:

```
(function submitEventHandler(){
    $('#submit1').on('click', Function.prototype.Modulo);
})();
```

Comment: Maybe you want to make something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/qma4org1/)? But I don't think it's a good idea to put function into `Function.prototype`. You can simply create `function Modulo() {}` or `var Modulo = function() {}` and use it in code.

Comment: I'm asking myself why I just didn't declare a regular function in the global scope, and use that....